# Stack Trace Error Handler and Promises Error Handler

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

I 've Error handler function:

```
function onError(message, source, lineno, colno, error) { sendRequestToSendMail(arguments) }
window.onerror = onError
```

I have also async tasks with promises and I want catch exceptions in them. I don't need to repeat yourself like:

```
doSomething1()
    .then(doSomething2(), onError)
    .then(doSomething3(), onError)
    .then(doSomething4(), onError)
```

How to implement global error handler for all promises (like window.onError) ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a global error handler (which doesn't sound like a great idea to me tbh), but since errors are propagated through the promise chain, you can shorten your code (and get rid of the repetition) by adding a final `.catch()` statement to your chain:

```
doSomething1()
    .then(doSomething2())
    .then(doSomething3())
    .then(doSomething4())
    .catch(onError)
```

That would catch any rejections thrown by any of the `doSomething*` functions.